# Android App not showing in PlayStore of certain devices (e.g samsung galaxy S4)

Tags: android, google-play

We published the app to Google PlayStore, but it does not seem to show on the PlayStore in latest available version of android (Kit Kat versions 4.4.2-4.4.3 ) on Samsung Galaxy4, HTC One (Model M7 2013) and Google Nexus tablet. However the app is visible on Android phones running Jelly Bean (android version 4.3.1). Here is the entire manifest file.

```
----------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xxx.yyyy"
android:versionCode="10" android:versionName="2.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="xxxApp">

    <activity
        android:label="xxxx"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"            
        android:name=".xxxActivity" >

        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".favorites" 
        android:label="Favorites">
    </activity>


    <activity android:name=".pin" 
        android:label="Pin">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".registration" 
        android:label="Registration Form">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".divisions" 
        android:label="Promotions">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".config" 
        android:label="Settings">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".resultsearch" 
        android:label="Result">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".detailstore" 
        android:label="Info">
    </activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Your app will not show up for many tablets because [your manifest requires that devices have telephony capability](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions).

Comment: When did you publish the app? It takes a while until it is visible on all devices. Can you post the package name?

Comment: @cygery - The app was published one month ago!

Comment: What does the app page on Google Play say about compatible Android versions?

Comment: @cygery - Google Play says supported in 4682 devices. For SamSung - it  shows 460 devices that includes Samsung Galaxy S4 Zoom, Galaxy S4 Mini but Samsung Galaxy S4 is not there but Galaxy S3 is there. For HTC I see HTC one listed, but I did not see HTC One (Model M7).

Comment: In the Developer Console you can open the page for your app, then APK and click on the row of the current APK (the one which lists the version code and name, upload date, status) to show the details. Which API levels are shown there?

Comment: @cygery APK Details    API levels 10+ 
Screen layouts 13 screen layouts 
normal@ldpi
normal@mdpi
normal@hdpi
normal@xhdpi
large@ldpi
large@mdpi
large@tvdpi
large@hdpi
large@xhdpi
xlarge@ldpi
xlarge@mdpi
xlarge@hdpi
xlarge@xhdpi
Localizations default language only 
Features 2 features 
android.hardware.TELEPHONY
android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN
Required permissions 6 permissions 
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.CALL_PHONE
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.SEND_SMS
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Then devices with xxhdpi displays (which includes 5" Full-HD displays) aren't supported. I assume that the final manifest is modified during your build process. Please check it.